# iOS: Core Data Fetch somehow not happening?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm programming some kind of budget app. At the bottom of the screen there is a label showing the total sum of costs for a certain category. I have the necessary label setup in the ViewWillAppear method however during the first loading of this view the label shows zero. If I navigate to the next VC in the navigation controller and back the sum is shown. Why? I've tried it with a seperate thread as well but that didn't help.

My viewWillAppear method:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //Initialize database
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if(!self.budgetDatabase){
        NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentationDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"BudgetDatabase"];
        self.budgetDatabase = [[UIManagedDocument alloc]initWithFileURL:url];
    }

    //Total cost/month will be fetched and formatted
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter =[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    //[self.tableView reloadData];

    self.sumLabel.text = [[DatabaseFetches budgetPerMonthForManagedObjectContext:self.budgetDatabase.managedObjectContext] getLocalizedCurrencyString];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}
```

And my DatabaseFetches class method:

```
+ (NSNumber *)budgetPerMonthForManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MainCategory"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"position" ascending:NO];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    CostsPeriodically *totalCostPerMonth = [[CostsPeriodically alloc]init];

    for (MainCategory *mainCategory in matches) {
        ...
    }

    return totalCostPerMonth.sumPerMonth;
}
```

Comment: are you sure, that `self.budgetDatabase.managedObjectContext` is initialised by the time you use it?

Comment: Try creating an `NSError` and log it for the `executeFetchRequest:error:` method and see what the error is, if any?

Comment: and is the `matches` array empty? Is there anything in the for loop that results in it returning nil?

Comment: Show the code where you load this view controller.